Question on nonlinear least squares
Consider the following equation for $Y>0$:
$$
(1) \quad \log(Y)=\log(\gamma)+\log(\alpha+\beta X)+\epsilon.
$$
Assume that $E(\epsilon| X)=c\neq 0$. What are the consequences of this assumption on the estimation of $(\gamma, \alpha, \beta)$? More precisely, does $c\neq 0$ only cause bias in the estimated intercept $\gamma$ (as in linear least squares), or the fact that this is a nonlinear least square model implies that $c\neq 0$ may cause bias also in estimated $(\alpha, \beta)$?
Update 1: Thanks to the comment below, we can answer the question as follows. Let $\zeta\equiv \epsilon -c$. Hence, (1) can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \log(Y)&=\log(\gamma)+\log(\alpha+\beta X)+\zeta+c,\\
&=\log(\gamma\exp(c))+\log(\alpha+\beta X)+\zeta.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, $c$ only causes a bias in the estimation of $\gamma$.
Update 2: To make sure I understand, let me complicate (1) as follows:
$$
(2) \quad \log(Y)=\log(\gamma)+\sum_{k=1}^K D_k[\log(\alpha_k+\beta_k X)+\epsilon_k],
$$
where $(D_1,\dots, D_K)$ is a vector of dummy variables in which exactly one element takes the value 1, and $E(\epsilon_k| D_1,\dots, D_K, X)=c\neq 0$. As before, I want to investigate which coefficients are biased by $c$. Let $\zeta_k\equiv \epsilon_k -c$. Hence, (2) can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \log(Y)&=\log(\gamma)+\sum_k D_k [\log(\alpha_k+\beta_k X+\zeta_k+c)],\\
&=\log(\gamma\exp(c\sum_k D_k ))+\sum_k D_k [\log(\alpha_k+\beta_k X) +\zeta_k],\\
&=\log(\gamma\exp(c))+\sum_k D_k [\log(\alpha_k+\beta_k X) +\zeta_k].
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, same answer as above.
Update 3: The comment below also suggests, more generally, that (1) is not identifiable. This is because (with $c=0$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\log(\gamma )+\log(\alpha+\beta X)+\epsilon\\
&=\log(\gamma  (\alpha+\beta X))\\
&=\log(\gamma  \alpha + \gamma   \beta X)+\epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, we can only identify $\gamma \alpha$ and $\gamma \beta$. Does the same issue hold in (2)? Yes, I think. In fact,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\log(\gamma )+\sum_k D_k[\log(\alpha_k+\beta_k X)+\epsilon_k],\\
&=\log(\gamma)  + \sum_k \log[(\alpha_k+\beta_k X)^{D_k}] + \sum_k D_k \epsilon_k,\\
&=\log(\gamma \Pi_{k}  (\alpha_k+\beta_k X)^{D_k})+ \sum_k D_k \epsilon_k.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

You can answer this yourself. Write $\epsilon = c + \zeta$ where now $E[\zeta]=0$ and notice you can incorporate $c$ into the $\log\gamma = \log(\gamma\exp(c))$ term, thereby changing $\gamma$ -- but nothing else.  Thus, if there are any consequences at all, they would lie in any distributional assumptions you might be making about $\epsilon:$ what are they? // Unfortunately, this is a terrible model because it's not identifiable: it's equivalent to $\log(Y)=\log(\alpha\gamma+(\beta\gamma)X)+\epsilon,$ demonstrating it really only has three parameters $c,$ $\alpha\gamma,$ and $\beta\gamma.$

@whuber:  Thanks. Could you please check the 3 updates added to my question, based on your comment?
